# Элементы в html накладываются друг на друга

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы они шли друг под другов, но элементы просто накладываются друг на друга. Можно конечно сделать для каждого элемента `top: n%` но это плохой вариант. Можно это как то исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, serif;
}
.main{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    left: 150px;
    top: 5%;
    width: 91%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#main_pic{
    background-image: url("../res/st.petersburg-main3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-position: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
}
header{
    font-size: xx-large;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 5%;
    border: darkblue;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #72afc0;
    color: white;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
aside{
    font-size: medium;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    left: 0%;
    top: 5%;
    background-color: #add8e6;
    color: white;
}
aside a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
aside ul{
    position: center;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
article{
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>О городе</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#menu-1.1">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <li>Туризм</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <li>Проживание</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</aside>
<header><p>Санкт-Питербург</p></header>
<div class="main">
    <div id="main_pic"></div>
    <article id="menu-1.1">
        <p>Санкт- Петербург – удивительный город с необычайно красивой архитектурой и интересной историей. Посмотреть на творенье Петра Великого съезжаются люди не только со всех уголков нашей страны, но и со всего мира. Сегодня расскажем, как и когда была основана северная столица нашего государства.

        Вернувшись из своей знаменитой поездки по Европе в 1698 году, Петр I осознал необходимость проведения масштабных реформ в стране. Император стремился направить вектор перемен в сторону запада - это касалось и образа жизни, одежды, привычек, архитектуры, строительства. Еще одним решением Петра стало основание новой столицы государства, которая отображала бы его стремление к европейским ценностям.

        В начале XVIII века между Россией и Швецией завязалась Северная война. В результате успешных действий нашей армии у шведов была отвоевана долина Невы. Для закрепления на новой территории Петром было принято решение возвести там крепость. Местом для постройки выбрали Заячий остров, отличавшийся удачным расположением. Именно там 27 мая 1703 года был заложен первый камень при строительстве Петропавловской крепости. Эту дату принято считать днем основания северной столицы.

        В список первых сооружений города, помимо Петропавловской Крепости, входят Кронштадт, Троицкая церковь, Гостиный двор, здание Адмиралтейства, Летний дворец Петра.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <p>текстекстекстекстекстекстекстекстекстекст</p>
    </article>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Absolute  уберите, он там не нужен

Comment: тогда у картинки питера отступа нет

Comment: style - margin/padding  class - wrapper/container

Answer (score 0):

Уберите `position:absolute` у класса `article`

```css
body{
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, serif;
}
.main{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    left: 150px;
    top: 5%;
    width: 91%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
#main_pic{
    background-image: url("../res/st.petersburg-main3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-position: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
}
header{
    font-size: xx-large;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 5%;
    border: darkblue;
    align-content: center;
    background-color: #72afc0;
    color: white;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
aside{
    font-size: medium;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 160px;
    left: 0%;
    top: 5%;
    background-color: #add8e6;
    color: white;
}
aside a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
aside ul{
    position: center;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
article{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>О городе</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#menu-1.1">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <li>Туризм</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <li>Проживание</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
            <li><a href="">История</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</aside>
<header><p>Санкт-Питербург</p></header>
<div class="main">
    <div id="main_pic"></div>
    <article id="menu-1.1">
        <p>Санкт- Петербург – удивительный город с необычайно красивой архитектурой и интересной историей. Посмотреть на творенье Петра Великого съезжаются люди не только со всех уголков нашей страны, но и со всего мира. Сегодня расскажем, как и когда была основана северная столица нашего государства.

        Вернувшись из своей знаменитой поездки по Европе в 1698 году, Петр I осознал необходимость проведения масштабных реформ в стране. Император стремился направить вектор перемен в сторону запада - это касалось и образа жизни, одежды, привычек, архитектуры, строительства. Еще одним решением Петра стало основание новой столицы государства, которая отображала бы его стремление к европейским ценностям.

        В начале XVIII века между Россией и Швецией завязалась Северная война. В результате успешных действий нашей армии у шведов была отвоевана долина Невы. Для закрепления на новой территории Петром было принято решение возвести там крепость. Местом для постройки выбрали Заячий остров, отличавшийся удачным расположением. Именно там 27 мая 1703 года был заложен первый камень при строительстве Петропавловской крепости. Эту дату принято считать днем основания северной столицы.

        В список первых сооружений города, помимо Петропавловской Крепости, входят Кронштадт, Троицкая церковь, Гостиный двор, здание Адмиралтейства, Летний дворец Петра.</p>
    </article>
    <article>
        <p>текстекстекстекстекстекстекстекстекстекст</p>
    </article>
</div>
</body>
```